# Flow not catching wrong prop types

Tags: reactjs, react-native, flowtype

just started using flow and I don't get why I'm not getting wrong prop type errors.

Setup:

- react-native: 0.48.3 (react-native-cli)
- flow-bin: @0.49.1 (as given in .flowconfig file, installed locally in dev-dependencies)

Tried creating dummy file (test.js).

```
// @flow

let x: string = 123;
```

Running npm run flow catches error that x has to be string, so probably no errors in setup.

**now with react:**

**DummyComponent.js**

```
  // @flow 

  type Props = {
     text: number,
  };

  const DummyComponent = ({ text } : Props) => (
    <View>
      <Text>{text}</Text>
    </View>
  );

export default DummyComponent
```

**App.js**

```
// @flow

 import DummyComponent from '../components/DummyComponent';


  const App = () => (
   <View>
    <DummyComponent text="foo"/>
   </View>
);
```

Running npm run flow gives no error, but text should be string not number.

Am I missing something ? It's my first time using flow, read starting guide, but missed something probably.

Thank you !

**EDIT:** Got it working with default exports, but when using:

```
import {DummyComponent} from '../components/DummyComponent'
```

no flow errors, what's the catch ? Anyone knows ?

Comment: Upgrading your `flow-bin` to 5x.x might help. Cuz if you copy and paste that into `flow repl`, you'll see it shows an error as expected.

Comment: Alright, Ill try 

Comment: Upgraded to 0.54.1, and getting  type errors from node_modules. Why is it so hard to setup flow.